# Assign ID based on commonality/groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've put together what I view to be overly complicated SQL to get to what I'm after.  I'm hoping for insight into a quicker and less complicated method.

What I'm after is the ability to assign an ID to groups of data where there is common groups of data across two columns.

For example I have the following subset of data:

```
CustID  PartID  RplcID
28       4        4
28       4        16
28       4        17
28       16       4
28       16       16
28       16       17
28       17       4
28       17       16
28       17       17
```

I want to create an ID for CustID=28 where there is overlap in the RplcID and PartID.  So in this example, PartID 4, 16, 17 all have RplcIDs in common (4, 16, 17).  As such, all of these pairs should have the same ID.

The method I'm using works (and is faster with temp tables instead of solely using CTEs) except for large datasets this thing is S-L-O-W.  I'm sure there's a more efficient method out there and hoping someone can lend their expertise.

I'm outlining my current approach for as much clarity into my muddled thinking as possible.

STEP 1
Generate temporary ID using `DENSE_RANK()` partitioned by CustID, ordered by PartID.

```
RowID   CustID  PartID  RplcID
1         28    16      16
1         28    17      16
1         28    4       16
2         28    16      17
2         28    17      17
2         28    4       17
3         28    16      4
3         28    17      4
3         28    4       4
```

STEP 2:
Then use these results and aggregate the PartIDs by using XML to create a comma separated string with which to group by.

```
RowID   CustID  RplcID  PartIDS
4         28    16       16,17,4
4         28    17       16,17,4
4         28    4        16,17,4
```

STEP 3:
And finally split out these groups using the assigned ID by parsing the XML.

```
RowID   CustID  PartID  RplcID
4         28          16    16
4         28          16    17
4         28          16    4
4         28          17    16
4         28          17    17
4         28          17    4
4         28          4     16
4         28          4     17
4         28          4     4
```

And the entirety of the SQL:

```
DECLARE @Parts TABLE
(
 CustID     VARCHAR(10),
 PartID     VARCHAR(10),
 RplcID     VARCHAR(10)

 )

Insert Into @Parts VALUES

('26','19','93'),('26','19','63'),
('26','31','93'),('26','31','63'),('26','32','93'),('26','32','63'),('26','33','93'),('26','33','63'),('26','34','93'),
('26','34','63'),('26','35','93'),('26','35','63'),('26','36','93'),('26','36','63'),('26','37','93'),('26','37','63'),
('26','38','93'),('26','38','63'),('26','39','93'),('26','39','63'),('27','40','95'),('27','41','94'),
('27','41','95'),('27','42','94'),('27','42','95'),('27','43','94'),('27','43','95'),('27','44','94'),('27','44','95'),
('27','45','94'),('27','45','95'),('27','46','94'),('27','46','95'),('27','47','94'),('27','47','95'),('27','48','94'),
('27','48','95'),('27','49','94'),('27','49','95'),('27','50','94'),('27','50','95'),('27','17','94'),('27','17','95'),
('27','51','94'),('27','51','95'),('27','52','94'),('27','52','95'),('27','53','94'),('27','53','95'),('27','54','94'),
('27','54','95'),('27','33','94'),('27','33','95'),('27','55','94'),('27','55','95'),('27','34','94'),('27','34','95'),
('27','56','94'),('27','56','95'),('27','35','94'),('27','35','95'),('27','57','94'),('27','57','95'),('27','58','94'),
('27','58','95'),('27','59','94'),('27','59','95'),('27','37','94'),('27','37','95'),('27','60','94'),('27','60','95'),
('27','61','94'),('27','61','95'),('27','62','94'),('27','62','95'),('27','63','94'),('27','63','95'),('27','64','94'),
('27','64','95'),('27','3','96'),('27','3','97'),('27','3','98'),('27','3','99'),('27','3','100'),('28','4','4'),
('28','4','16'),('28','4','17'),('28','16','4'),('28','16','16'),('28','16','17'),('28','17','4'),('28','17','16'),
('28','17','17')
;


--Step 1: Create the initial ID

SELECT DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY r.CustID 
                    ORDER BY r2.RplcID) AS RowID, 
                r.CustID, 
                r.BuyID, 
                r2.RplcID 
INTO #tmp
FROM   @Parts r 
       JOIN @Parts r1 
         ON r.CustID = r1.CustID 
            AND r.RplcID = r1.RplcID 
       JOIN @Parts r2 
         ON r.CustID = r2.CustID 
            AND r1.BuyID = r2.BuyID   


--Step 2: Group the BuyIDs
SELECT DENSE_RANK() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY CustID, BuyIDs) AS RowID, 
       * 
INTO #tmp2
FROM   (SELECT CustID, 
               Rtrim(RplcID) RplcID, 
               Stuff((SELECT ',' + Rtrim(BuyID) 
                      FROM   #tmp RSLT2 
                      WHERE  RSLT2.ROWID = RSLT.ROWID 
                             AND RSLT2.CustID = RSLT.CustID 
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [BuyIDs] 
        FROM   #tmp RSLT 
        GROUP  BY RSLT.CustID, 
                  RSLT.ROWID, 
                  RSLT.RplcID)A   



--Step 3: Using the grouped BuyIDs, split the strings using XML and assign RowID
SELECT RowID, 
       CustID, 
       BuyID,
       RplcID

INTO #tmp3
FROM    (SELECT RowID, 
               CustID, 
               n.r.value('.','varchar(10)') AS BuyID, 
               RplcID
        FROM   #tmp2 
               CROSS APPLY(SELECT Cast('<r>' + Replace(BuyIDs, ',', '</r><r>') 
                                       + '</r>' AS XML)) AS S(xmlcol) 
               CROSS APPLY s.xmlcol.nodes('r') AS n(r))A 
Order by RowID  

Select * from #tmp3 where CustID='28'

Select distinct BuyID 
from #tmp3
where CustID='28'   

Select distinct RplcID 
from #tmp3
where CustID='28'
```